# Equality between q shifted factorials and sum with partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

I am looking at WilliamY.C.Chen,Qing-HuHou,and Alain Lascoux proof for the Gauss Identity in q shifted factorials. At some point they claim that it is easy to see that

$$
\frac{q^r}{(q ; q)_r}=\sum_{\lambda \in P_r} q^{|\lambda|}
$$

Where $ \lambda $ is a partition and $ \ P_r $ is the set of partitions $ \lambda $ with maximal component r.

I really cannot see why this is the case, can anyone help?

Comment: What does $|\lambda|$ mean? The number of elements in the partition?

Comment: It’s the weight of the partition (sun of the parts)

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic 'number of partitions with maximum part $k$' equals the 'number of partitions with $k$ parts'.

This can be seen by reading a partition in two ways. For example, $53221$ looks like

```
*
*
**
****
*****
```

and if you read the row lengths you get $54211$.

```
*
**
**
***
*****
```

with one being the reflection about $y=x$ of the other.

Comment: Ok this is clear but I don’t get how this helps with the equality I’m asking in the question

Comment: @guila; the LHS is the q-Pochhammer, and gives a part of size $r$ in the numerator, and any number of $\le$ parts in the denominator. The RHS counts by the weight of each partition in a $P_r$.

Comment: Ah wow yes this makes it incredibly clear, thanks